# How do I set a different umask per directory?

Tags: linux, permissions

This is seems like it would be a very common configuration question, but I don't know how phrase it properly enough for Google to help.

I am using a server with NFS to serve up both home directories and a shared documents directory mounted as `/opt/shared`. When a user creates a file in his home directory, I'd like the default file mode to be 600. However, if he creates a file in `/opt/shared`, it should be set to 660. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for a function that is included in bindfs. See link below for details.

HOWTO: Change umask, permissions, ownership etc. of a folder

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/blog/kribor-618996/howto-change-umask-permissions-ownership-etc-of-a-folder-using-bindfs-23934/